# Using Batch file, how do I check if the first line of multiple csv files are exactly the same?

Tags: csv, batch-file

For example, I have 3 CSV files: CSV1, CSV2, CSV3

Each csv file has this format -

```
Issue type,Issue key,Date,Status
1,2,30/12/2018,Available
1,5,31/12/2018,Available
```

And I want to check if the column names (eg. Issue type,Issue key,Date,Status) match for all 3 csv files. How do I do this in Batch?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Comment: So you want to test if all 3 files have the same headers?

Comment: Yes @GerhardBarnard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this example the long way around in order to show you what exactly happens.
I am using three test files as examples `test1.csv`, `test2.csv` and `test3.csv`:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type test1.csv') do set "test1=%%~i" & goto :check2
goto :eof
:check2
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type test2.csv') do set "test2=%%~i" & goto :check3
goto :eof
:check3
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type test3.csv') do set "test3=%%~i" & goto :final
goto :eof
:final
if "%test1%" == "%test2%" (set "onetwo=true") else (set "onetwo=false")
if "%test2%" == "%test3%" (set "twothree=true") else (set "twothree=false")
if "%test1%" == "%test3%" (set "onethree=true") else (set "onethree=false")
if "%onetwo%%twothree%%onethree%"=="truetruetrue" echo All 3 files have the same header
if "%onetwo%%twothree%%onethree%"=="falsefalsetrue" echo only 1 and 3 martches, but not 2
if "%onetwo%%twothree%%onethree%"=="truefalsefalse" echo only 1 and 2 martches, but not 3
if "%onetwo%%twothree%%onethree%"=="falsetruefalse" echo only 2 and 3 martches, but not 1
if "%onetwo%%twothree%%onethree%"=="falsefalsefalse" echo None of the headers match.
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! @Gerhard Barnard! I'm new to batch files (1 week experience) so this really helps. Also, how would I use this to loop through all csv files in a given directory (ie. C:\Users\hideyuki\Downloads)

Comment: Unfortunately that is a completely different question. We do not change questions on the fly, you would need to ask another question.